# I get error when trying to subscribe to the getStream Websocket

Tags: getstream-io

Currently, I am integrating websockets for the feeds using GetStream JS library.
But I can't subscribe to the websocket by following the instruction

I have created Flat Feeds and it's working fine. I can do all the actions with activities. But I need to integrate my app with websocket so that it can update the feed live.
I've followed the steps that described in the feed document

```
async initializeStream(profile, followings = []) {
    try {
      const { peerID } = profile;
      const response = await getStreamToken(peerID);
      const { token } = response;
      this.token = token;
      this.client = stream.connect(STREAM_API_KEY, token, STREAM_APP_ID);
      await this.createUser(profile);
      this.feed = this.client.feed('user', peerID, token);
      this.globalFeed = this.client.feed('user', 'all', token);
      return true;
    } catch (err) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This is stream initialization part and it works fine without any flaw.

And below is subscription function:

```
subscribe (subscribingFunction) {
    return this.feed.subscribe(subscribingFunction);
  }
```

And this one is how I am using subscription function to integrate websocket:

```
StreamClient.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log('stream - update received');
      console.log(data);
      // return emitter({ type: 'STREM/UPDATE_RECEIVED', payload: data });
    }).then(response => {
      console.log('success', response)
    }).catch(response => {
      console.log('failure', response)
    });
```

Expected Result:
Websocket subscription is success and I can get the live updates through it.

Result:
I am getting this error when trying to subscribe to websocket:

```
klass {code: null, params: Array(0), message: "Failed to authenticate. Please check your API Token, App ID and Feed ID."}
```

Can you point me out what went wrong with this configuration?

Here's code for the getStreamToken function:

```
export const getStreamToken = (userId) => {
  const apiURL = `${tokenServerAPI}/getToken?user_id=${userId}`;
  const headers = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      authorization: `Basic ${base64.encode('ob_stream_user:ob_stream_pwd')}`,
    },
  };
  return fetch(
    apiURL,
    headers,
  ).then(response => response.json()).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: can you add `getStreamToken` as well?

Comment: Hi @TommasoBarbugli,
Please check the function above.